# Convert timestamp (UTC?) to UNIX timestamp using JQuery

Tags: jquery, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm pulling dates from a web service using JQuery and they look like this:

```
2013-05-20T23:59:59+01:00
```

Is there a quick way to convert this format to a UNIX timestamp using JQuery? So it looks like this:

```
1369090799
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just plain JavaScript. No need of jQuery in this case. You can do

```
var date = '2013-05-20T23:59:59+01:00'
alert(Date.parse(date)/1000)
```